# PHP Header Redirect with parameter

Tags: php, redirect, parameters

So I want to use a basic header redirect to bring a variable from one page to another. This seems really basic, but everywhere I look people are asking about more complex situations and it makes it harder to grasp. Basically, I have a variable $user = "root" and I simply want to pass this to another page using `Header("Location: query.php".$user);`

First of all, I want to make sure that this redirect will send my variable correctly.

Second, how exactly will I retrieve it on the other side. Generally if I were using a submit button posting to a form, I would use something as this `$user = ($_POST["user"]);`. Would I retrieve the parameter in a similar fashion in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check for this : `header("Location: query.php?user=".$user);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For send variable

```
$user = 'test';
Header("Location: query.php?user=".$user);
```

For receive the value of user variable

```
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
```

I hope it will help to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning variable $user = "root"; now this variable user will stores the value root ok . what you did is you passed value but not the name which store the value. so that you can retrieve it .
change

```
header("Location: query.php?".$user);//it will pass  as query.php?root
to
header("Location: query.php?user=".$user);
$user = ($_POST["user"]);//to get the value
```