# Why doesn't the redirect work? How would you fix it?

Tags: php, if-statement, redirect, echo

```
if ($stmtselect->rowCount() > 0) {
    header("refresh:5;url=https://www.websitename.com");
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $user;
    echo 'You have signed in successfully!';
    die();
}else {
    header("refresh:5;url=index.php");
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password or Email';
    die();
}
```

I have the header first so why doesn't it work?
Just so you know, this page is a form. It submits stuff to me. If it works then I want it to redirect after the echo.

I get this error.

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 [Violation] 'load' handler took 1365ms
```

It might have to do with the fact that the echo is in the form of an error. Like this I guess.

[image: Echo]

If not then I don't know. Please help.

EDIT-

Here's the javascript.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(e){

            var valid = this.form.checkValidity();

            if(valid){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
            }

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jslogin.php',
                data:  {username: username, password: password, email: email},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    if($.trim(data) === "1"){
//                      setTimeout(' window.location.href =  "index.php"', 1000);
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href =  "https://kaden-tech.github.io"', 1000);
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert('There were errors while doing the operation.');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

Please don't say anything about password hashing.

Edit-

Index.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(0);
session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['id16365171_hello_world_accounts'])){
        header("Location: login.php");
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_GET['logout'])){
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION);
        header("Location: login.php");
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="0J0VoOQKJVdlFn7Us8_s97YvAXLirkBVrJ75FGLe_Ds" />
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Welcome to index</p>


<a href="index.php?logout=true">Logout</a>
</body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
    session_start();
    
if(isset($_SESSION['id16365171_hello_world_accounts'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="0J0VoOQKJVdlFn7Us8_s97YvAXLirkBVrJ75FGLe_Ds" />
    <title>Hello World | Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="user_card">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="brand_logo_container">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Programming Knowledge logo">
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-user"></em></span>                 
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input_user" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-key"></em></span>                  
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-1">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-inbox"></em></span>                    
                        </div>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input_pass" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-1 login_container">
                <button type="button" name="button" id="login" class="btn login_btn">Login</button> 
            </div>
            </form>
            <div class="mt-3 mb-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                    Don't have an account? <a href="temp/home.php" class="ml-2">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#login').click(function(e){

            var valid = this.form.checkValidity();

            if(valid){
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var password = $('#password').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
            }

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'jslogin.php',
                data:  {username: username, password: password, email: email},
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    if($.trim(data) === "1"){
//                      setTimeout(' window.location.href =  "index.php"', 1000);
                        setTimeout(' window.location.href =  "https://kaden-tech.github.io"', 1000);
                    }
                },
                error: function(data){
                    alert('There were errors while doing the operation.');
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jslogin.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
require_once('loginconfig.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//$emailval = ['email'];

//$check = (strpos($emailval,'@'));

//if ($check === false){
//    echo 'We require valid email';
//}else{


//$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","*********","**********","*************");


$sql = "SELECT * FROM *********** WHERE username=? and password=? and email=? LIMIT 1";
$stmtselect = $db->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmtselect->execute([$username, $password, $email]);
$user = $stmtselect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($stmtselect->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv = refresh content = 5; url = https://www.example.com />';
    $_SESSION[`*********`] = $user;
    echo 'You have signed in successfully!';
    die();
}else {
    echo '<meta http-equiv = refresh content = 5; url = https://www.example.com/otherpage />';
    $_SESSION[`accounts`] = $user;
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password or Email';
    die();
}
```

loginconfig.php

```
<?php

$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "password";
$db_name = "database name";

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='. $db_name . ';charset=utf8', $db_user, $db_pass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This is my code.

Please find a way to stop ajax and allow this to be functional.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain if `refresh` is a header in any official spec. I know it was used in `meta` tags and that some browsers supported it, but you might be better with a [Location directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33795180/231316) which is supported everywhere.

Comment: refresh works, I used it for another webpage today. It just that this part isnt working.

Comment: I'd make sure that your PHP is set to display warnings and errors, just in case there's a "headers already sent" warning in there. I'd also include some `exit` or `die` after you are done with `echo` to make sure no other code is changing your headers (for instance, if you happened to be caught in an OB)

Comment: i did that. Still doesn't work.

Comment: For the first refresh, I'm almost positive that you need to include the full protocol, so `header("refresh:5;url=https://example.com");`

Comment: I tried that too.

Comment: The next step for debugging it to open up your browser's inspection tools and look at the headers being sent. If the header is present, then it is an issue with your browser, and you can check the console to see if there are some extra message. If the header isn't present, that is a server/code problem. Whichever one it is (present or not present), it would probably be best to update your question with all of that information.

Comment: Oh! I didn't think of that. I will try it right now.

Comment: I know you said that you used a `refresh` on other pages and it worked, but would you be willing to try a `Location` redirect instead? The latter is in the official specifications whereas the former was made up (probably by Netscape or Microsoft) and I wouldn't recommend relying on it, even if it sometimes works.

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: The fact you have an alert box showing in your screenshot indicates there must be some JavaScript involved in the scenario somewhere, but you haven't shown it. All we know is that jQuery takes look long to load, for some reason. It's unclear whether that has anything to do with your problem or not, to be honest. Try creating a clean front-end page without jQuery in it or any other distractions, and see if you still have an issue when using this header. Then add things back in one at a time until the problem recurs. That'll help you to narrow down the influencing factor(s).

Comment: ok ill show it.

Comment: `Please don't say anything about password hashing`...why would we? You haven't shown any code relevant to that. You don't hash passwords on the client-side anyway.

Comment: Anyway your JS code reveals that you're doing this via AJAX...which is why the header doesn't work. JavaScript doesn't automatically process or act on headers returned from AJAX requests (unlike what the browser does with headers from conventional non-AJAX requests). You'd have to write code to look at the headers and decide to act on them. But...why would you want to, in this case? The whole point of AJAX is to allow you to _stay on the same page and not need to refresh_. If you want to refresh the whole page after this request completes, then don't use AJAX to begin with.

Comment: ok. I see. I am afraid that when I remove ajax it will break the code. Can you rewrite my javascript to fix that problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: `I am afraid that when I remove ajax it will break the code`...why exactly? And did you try yet? What was the result? Were you unable to fix it somehow? It might need a little bit of refactoring, yes, but it shouldn't be a big deal. Unfortunately I can't see the form or the button which triggers the AJAX, or anything about the `checkValidity()` JS function, so it's hard for me to give any specific advice on what changes would be needed.

Comment: ok so I just remove the word ajax?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230081/discussion-between-kaden-skinner-and-adyson).

Comment: `so I just remove the word ajax`...er, no, lol. I mean remove the whole functionality which handles the button click and triggers the AJAX request, so that the form goes back to posting normally. You _might_ need some other changes to the form as well, but I don't know because I can't see it. (P.S. Now you've said that I'm a little bit worried that you have absolutely no idea what this code does or how it works??)

Comment: ok. So if I post all my code you might be able to help?

Comment: I don't know what "all" your code consists of, but certainly the things I've mentioned above would be necessary, yes.

Comment: ok ima update the question

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's irrelevant code for this issue, but actually this bit in index.php:`if(!isset($_SESSION['id16365171_hello_world_accounts'])){
        header("Location: login.php");
    }` needs to be `if(!isset($_SESSION['id16365171_hello_world_accounts'])){
        header("Location: login.php"); die();
    }`. If you don't `die()` after that, then the HTML of your index page will still be returned in the response (even if the browser doesn't display it due to the header). This means bots / crawlers can still see your supposedly-private page contents, so it's a security bug.

Comment: ok I will update that.

Comment: Another thing, you should not use the database `root` account with your application. That's for administrators only - it has all privileges, so if there is accidentally any SQL-related vulnerability in your PHP, then you've just left your whole database server open for hackers to do anything they want. Make a separate SQL account which has only the privileges the application actually _needs_ in order to work. Use that account for testing development as well as live use, so you don't get any nasty permission-related surprises when you go live.

Comment: I edited the code. I had deleted the numbers before root. I am using 000webhostapp.com for this. So it is not just root.

Comment: They don't let me have all privilages anyway.

Comment: Ok sure but you wouldn't use root either in your localhost development environment (if you have one). Anyway I am working on an answer to your main question.

Comment: right. Ok. Like on xampp

Comment: Yes indeed. P.S. Why do you ask for username _and_ email when logging on? That's very unusual and almost certainly unnecessary. Username and password should be sufficient to uniquely identify the user, unless you have an unusual design.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

Comment: Good question. I am a learner and had trouble doing posting three variables. When I finally got it I refused to delete it in fear that I might forget. I could comment it out though.

Comment: The website just stores the info in a database and when you login it just says that you logged in successfully. I will look into it.

Comment: `The website just stores the info in a database`...yes that's fine, but it's how you store the passwords which is the problem - if you store them as plain text then a hacker could get access to all the passwords if they manage to hack into your database, and from there steal users' account details. If they have any personal info in there, or things like credit card details, anything like that, then you have a serious issue. it might not be so significant for this site perhaps, but if you get into the habit of doing security properly from the beginning, you won't have to learn again later.

Comment: alright. I am a 15 year old that is learning all this. I wont be storing credit card details but I will definitely  look into that.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use a header for this, try echoing the meta redirect tag.

```
if ($stmtselect->rowCount() > 0) {
    echo '<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "5; url = https://www.example.com" />';
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $user;
    echo 'You have signed in successfully!';
    die();
}else {
    echo '<meta http-equiv = "refresh" content = "5; url = https://www.example.com/otherpage" />';
    $_SESSION['accounts'] = $user;
    echo 'Incorrect Username or Password or Email';
    die();
}
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't redirect only says the code.

Comment: i sent you an email

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make a lot of sense to use AJAX if you're just going to redirect the user to another page immediately after it's finished. Here's a more conventional login procedure based on your code, which doesn't use AJAX at all.

Summary of changes:

- make the form button `type="submit"`
- make the form do a POST
- remove all JavaScript code
- delete jsLogin.php, and move relevant code from it to login.php and wrap inside an `if` which checks if the form has been submitted before trying to process it.
- output an error message if login fails. If it succeeds just set the session variables and redirect to index.php

**login.php:**

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);
session_start();
    
if(isset($_SESSION['id16365171_hello_world_accounts'])){
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}

require_once('loginconfig.php');

//process the form submission, if any
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $message = "";

  if (isset($email) && isset($username) && isset($password)) {
  
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? and password=? and email=? LIMIT 1";
    $stmtselect = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result = $stmtselect->execute([$username, $password, $email]);
    $user = $stmtselect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($user) {
      $_SESSION['id16365171_hello_world_accounts'] = $user;
      header("Location: index.php");
      die();
    }
    else
    {
      $message = "Incorrect Username or Password or Email";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $message = "Please enter all required details";
  }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="0J0VoOQKJVdlFn7Us8_s97YvAXLirkBVrJ75FGLe_Ds" />
    <title>Hello World | Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container h-100">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="user_card">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="brand_logo_container">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" class="brand_logo" alt="Programming Knowledge logo">
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center form_container">
                <?php if ($message != "") echo $message; ?> <!-- you might want to add some more HTML round that to make it display nicely -->
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-user"></em></span>                 
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control input_user" placeholder="Username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-key"></em></span>                  
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control input_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-1">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><em class="fas fa-inbox"></em></span>                    
                        </div>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input_pass" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="rememberme" class="custom-control-input" id="customControlInline">
                            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customControlInline">Remember me</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mt-1 login_container">
                <button type="submit" name="button" id="login" class="btn login_btn">Login</button> 
            </div>
            </form>
            <div class="mt-3 mb-1">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center links">
                    Don't have an account? <a href="temp/home.php" class="ml-2">Sign Up</a>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

P.S. Please also take note of the various security points I made in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript says

```
if($.trim(data) === "1"){
```

Which means that if you echo out `1` then do something.

You should either change the php to echo out `1` or change the javascript to

```
if($.trim(data) === "You have successfully signed in!"){
```

The the redirect would work.

One more thing-
Your redirect would be better if you did

```
setTimeout(function(){ document.location.replace("http://www.example.com"); }, 1000)
```